# Can I move a Wordpress installation to an IP (without domain name)?

Tags: installation, ip

I have a Wordpress installation in a subfolder of a domain:

http://www.example.com/wordpress

I want to move it to a hosting space with no domain name:

http://123.123.123.123

Will it work? I want to try Duplicator or maybe manually, but I don't know if it will work without a domain name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work as far as I know.

You need to make sure that you have the two URL constants pointing to the right folder on your webspace.

See in your database XX_options table:

siteurl: 123.123.123.123/wordpress

home: 123.123.123.123/wordpress

These fields can be edited via Settings > General below the 2 fields of title and subtitle, so there is no need to fool around in the database.

Comment: Will it work in the root as well? (not inside the wordpress folder): http://123.123.123.123

Comment: Yes, same principle..

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming!